# Як правильно вимовляти (та відмінювати) десяткові числа?

Tags: відмінювання, числівники

Як вимовляти:

1. 15,8457639
2. 13,7 млрд (хтось мені сказав "тринадцять і сім мільярдів, можна так сказати?)
3. близько 20,1 млрд
4. близько 21
5. близько 14,356

Дякую))